# 500 Internal Server Error After chown a Folder

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I get 500 Internal Server Error after I ran the following command:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Here is the last lines inside the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file.

```
/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.158229 2017] [:error] [pid 3824] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.158240 2017] [:error] [pid 3824] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.158250 2017] [:error] [pid 3824] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.159175 2017] [:error] [pid 3823] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.159264 2017] [:error] [pid 3823] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.159276 2017] [:error] [pid 3823] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:40.159286 2017] [:error] [pid 3823] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.167617 2017] [:error] [pid 3826] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.167750 2017] [:error] [pid 3826] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.167761 2017] [:error] [pid 3826] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.167772 2017] [:error] [pid 3826] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.171448 2017] [:error] [pid 3825] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.171594 2017] [:error] [pid 3825] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.171606 2017] [:error] [pid 3825] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.171617 2017] [:error] [pid 3825] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.175442 2017] [:error] [pid 3827] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.175572 2017] [:error] [pid 3827] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.175584 2017] [:error] [pid 3827] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.175595 2017] [:error] [pid 3827] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.179316 2017] [:error] [pid 3828] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.179423 2017] [:error] [pid 3828] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.179434 2017] [:error] [pid 3828] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    [Mon Nov 20 23:36:41.179444 2017] [:error] [pid 3828] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    Error Opening file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
    [Mon Nov 20 23:37:47.607307 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3825] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 112.215.237.140:65518] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
    [Mon Nov 20 23:37:47.610882 2017] [core:error] [pid 3825] [client 112.215.237.140:65518] End of script output before headers: index.php
    suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
    [Mon Nov 20 23:41:20.368400 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1896] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 112.215.237.140:16835] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
    [Mon Nov 20 23:41:20.368521 2017] [core:error] [pid 1896] [client 112.215.237.140:16835] End of script output before headers: index.php
    suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
    [Mon Nov 20 23:45:16.218950 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3828] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 112.215.237.140:26790] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
    [Mon Nov 20 23:45:16.219014 2017] [core:error] [pid 3828] [client 112.215.237.140:26790] End of script output before headers: index.php
    [Mon Nov 20 23:49:45.767925 2017] [core:crit] [pid 3793] (13)Permission denied: [client 112.215.237.140:40527] AH00529: /var/www/ispconfig/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/ispconfig/' is executable
    [Mon Nov 20 23:51:46.767779 2017] [core:crit] [pid 3828] (13)Permission denied: [client 112.215.237.140:62852] AH00529: /var/www/ispconfig/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/ispconfig/' is executable
    [Mon Nov 20 23:51:59.908490 2017] [core:crit] [pid 3825] (13)Permission denied: [client 112.215.237.140:11735] AH00529: /var/www/ispconfig/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/ispconfig/' is executable
    suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
    [Mon Nov 20 23:52:35.614416 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3826] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 112.215.237.140:58862] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
    [Mon Nov 20 23:52:35.614480 2017] [core:error] [pid 3826] [client 112.215.237.140:58862] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

What would be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Who is the owner of the files at `/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat`?

Comment: @phandolin yes, I do, it does not work even I already take its ownership back to default.

Comment: So you're saying `webuser` owns those files? Or is that another account?

Comment: It is root user.